# DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView get rows

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView;`
  there is also a pattern of Excel - shablon.xlt.
I want when you click on "go" to save the template data from gridView.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
            ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\shablon.xlt");
            ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];
            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "hz1";
            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "hz2";
            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "dfdsf";
            ObjExcel.Visible = true;ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
        }
```

I need to ObjWorkSheet.Cells [3, 1] = "hz1"; insert data from a similar cell gridView.
e.g. ObjWorkSheet.Cells [3, 1] = gridView.GetRow (1); but such a mechanism in gridviev I have not found

Comment: You need to get the value of the cell?

Comment: yes absolutely. But I can not do that. My task - to generate a report from the data. I found only one method gridView.ExportToXls () but it does not suit me. I want to manage the data that take from gridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to export the data in `GridView` to Excel, `GridView` [already provides an option](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q430217)

```
gridView1.ExportToXls("export.xls");
```

If at all you want to do it manually, you can do it using [GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic1302) method

```
var firstCellValue = gridView.GetRowCellValue(0,"ColumnName");
```

Comment: var firstCellValue = gridView.GetRowCellValue(0,"ColumnName"); 
I will not return nor any result

Comment: "ColumnName" is a sample, you have you give your column name over there

Comment: yes I understood it) I write a column name as I have in the table, but nothing happens

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but this is how you have to do. I've used it successfully. In fact still using.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution and receive data from the DataSource. anyway for your answer thank you so much!